# What does `var MyConstructor = function MyConstructor()` do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, yeoman

What's the difference between:

```js
var NodestrapGenerator = module.exports = function NodestrapGenerator() {
  yeoman.generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);
  // more code here
};
```

and:

```js
var NodestrapGenerator = module.exports = function() {
  yeoman.generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);
  // more code here
};
```

I'm trying to write my yeoman-generator's index.js in coffeescript, but apparently the second snippet isn't the same because it's not working! Thanks!

Comment: There should be no difference.  The important part is that `module.exports` is set.

Comment: some code not show here must sniff the code and expects to see arguments.callee.name to correlate with the publicly-named variable.

Comment: The first is a named function expression, the second an anonymous function expression.  Some where in the `// more code here`, the name must be referred to for it to matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var NodestrapGenerator = module.exports = function NodestrapGenerator() { ... };
```

This is a *named function* called "NodestrapGenerator", assigned to variable `NodestrapGenerator`.

```
var NodestrapGenerator = module.exports = function() { ... };
```

This is an *unnamed function* aka. *anonymous function*, which gets assigned to variable `NodestrapGenerator`.

In the end, they're both referencing the same function, so no difference which way you write it.

See this for more explanation: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

As to why it's not working, its probably because the code is looking for the named function `NodestrapGenerator` to verify that it's the function it should be using, not some random anonymous function.

FYI, `function` has a property `name` which will get set to `"NodestrapGenerator"` in *named function* (first example), but will be empty string `""` in *anonymous function* (second example). (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)